# String type with space + accepted types (recursively) in typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, typescript-generics

```js
type AcceptedClass = "one" | "two" | "three";

type ClassName = `${AcceptedClass} ${ClassName}`;

const className: ClassName = "one two three";
const className2: ClassName = "two one three one three";
const className3: ClassName = "three";
const className4: ClassName = "three one two three one two";
```

I'd like to create type like code (below),
But there's something error

`Type alias 'ClassName' circularly references itself.ts(2456)`

Is it not possible make that types in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a circular dependency when using type literals.

Think about it like this:

- TS needs replace ${ClassName} with all the possibilities that `ClassName` can take
- When you use ${ClassName} inside the definition of ${ClassName} it will need to include the 1st iteration for ClassName
- This will go on for ever.

Templated types are fully extended so you cannot have an unbounded type, which you are trying to do. TS has a hard limit of 100k terms in a union type.

You could use something like this, but with limited availability:

```
const type ClassName = `${AcceptedClass} ${AcceptedClass} ${AcceptedClass} ${AcceptedClass}`;
```

Comment: Thanks, so your saying is cannot use types like `ClassName` right?

Comment: (What I wanted is fixing className string type)

Comment: You can use other types, you cannot use the type you are actually defining now. I've updated my answer with a suggestion